# Bootstrap grid layout not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to structure a program of mine so that it goes: 
Row:col-3,col-3,col-3. Row:col-6,col-6.
But it's not working at all and i'm not sure if it's because of css because i've checked multiple bootstrap layouts and i'm sure this is correct.

Html

```
        <div class="container-fluid content">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h4>Select your gender:</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="option" "col-lg-6">
                            <input id="male" value="male" name="w" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="male">Male</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option" "col-lg-6">
                            <input id="female" value="female" name="w" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="female">Female</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h4>Enter your age:</h4>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Years" input type="Number" min="5" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h4>Enter your bodyweight:</h4>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TbBodyWeight" runat="server" placeholder="Pounds" input type="Number" min ="50" max ="500" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h4>Select your level of daily activity:</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="option" "col-3">
                            <input id="Activity1" value="Activity1" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Activity1">Light: The day is spent mainly sitting down (Driver, desk job).</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option" "col-3">
                            <input id="Activity2" value="Activity2" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Activity2">Moderate: The day is spent mainly on your feet (Teacher, salesman).</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option" "col-3">
                            <input id="Activity3" value="Activity3" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Activity3">Very: The day is spent mainly doing physical activities (Waitress, mailman).</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option col-3">
                            <input id="Activity4" value="Activity4" name="Activity" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Activity4">Extreme: The day is spent mainly doing heavy physical labour (Carpenter, builder).</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h4>Select the food type you go for the most:</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="option">
                            <input id="Food1" value="Food1" name="Food" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Food1">High Carbs: Candies, cereals.</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input id="Food2" value="Food2" name="Food" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Food2">Moderate Carbs: Tomato soup, broccoli.</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input id="Food3" value="Food3" name="Food" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Food3">Moderate Fats: Tuna, lean mince.</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input id="Food4" value="Food4" name="Food" checked="" type="radio" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="Food4">High Fats: Avocado, nuts.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="">
                    <asp:Button ID="Calculate" class="Calculate" runat="server" OnClick="Calculate_Click" Text="Calculate" />
                </div>
                 <br />
                 <div class="">
                    <asp:Label ID="WriteCalculation" class="CalculationLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: white;
//background-image: url("weightlift_rotator.jpg");
background-size: auto;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 400px;
margin-right: 400px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
border: 2px solid black;
box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.heading {
background-color: white;
}

.line-separator{
height:1px;
background: #717171;
border-bottom:1px solid #313030;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
}
html { 
background: url("weight2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
text-align: center;
border-left: thin;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-left: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
//border: 2px solid black;
 }

p {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
border-left: thin;
}


h4 {
//background-color: #4c4cff;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
//text-align: center;
text-align: justify;
border-left: thin;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 1px;
margin-right: 1px;
//border: 2px solid black;
}

.Calculate {
background-color: #4c4cff;
color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.Calculate:hover {
background-color: white;
color: black;
text-align: center;
//display: inline;
}

.CalculationLabel {
/*background-color: #8aacb8;*/
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
text-align: justify;
border-left: thin;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
```

}

```
.option {
//background-color: #4c4cff;
color: black;
//border: 1px solid black;
//border-radius: 2px;
/*padding: 15px 32px;*/
text-align: justify;
text-decoration: none;
/*display: inline-block;*/
font-size: 17px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
transition-duration: 0.4s
}

.option:checked {
background-color: white;
color: black;  
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `col-lg-x`, use `col-sm-x`

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your column sizes at the lower-end of your aim, as the system scales up like:

```
col-xs-* col-sm-* col-lg-* col-xl-*
```

here's a good [table on bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Comment: I looked at the table, and tried the different size; col-xs, col-sm etc, but none of them seem to do the trick, different columns in the same row are still stacked one under another

Comment: I guess I'm not visualizing what the layout result you're wanting is, however, I did this pen up as an example of how offsets work: 

http://codepen.io/mixitman/pen/qNwwOR

offset is calculated as (total-cols - row-cols)/2  (so a hitch is that you need even-sized columns)

Comment: The layout you've used is exactly correct for what I'm going for, and I've just tried out the way you coded it but still no luck, this is how it's being shown currently: http://imgur.com/a/bMzGZ

Comment: Ok, I found my problem which was really stupid, I forgot to have the bootstrap reference:<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">. But thank you for the help.